# VueJS component's Created()/Mounted() event is getting called while leaving the component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an AngularJS application where I'm using few components of Vue (version 2).

The Navigation bar of the app is in AngularJS.

When I switch between different navigation options (Home/Support), I'm loading the related Vue components.

VueJS project is built using *npm run buid-lib* and linked in angularJS app (*npm link*). Library name is **myVueApp**.

Using ngVue library to integrate Vue with AngularJS.

**Code to load Vue Components in AngularJS app (as plugin):**

```
(function() {
'use strict';

if (typeof myVueApp !== 'undefined') {
    var VueContainer = myVueApp.components.VueContainer,
        plugins = myVueApp.plugins;
}

angular
    .module('my.vue.config', ['ngVue', 'ngVue.plugins'])
    .config(function($ngVueProvider) {
        $ngVueProvider.setRootVueInstanceProps(plugins);
    })

    // Add Vue components here
    .value('VueContainer', VueContainer);
})();
```

In HTML page, I'm loading the component like below example:

**Home.Html** **(In AngularJS)**

```
<div>
     <vue-component name="VueContainer"></vue-component>
</div>
```

**Routing of the Vue Components in Angular Controller:**

```
var ngModule = angular.module('home.content', ['ui.router']);
ngModule.config(function ($stateProvider) {
$stateProvider
  .state('home.content', {
    url: '?home&t',
    controller: 'HomeCtrl as HomeCtrl ',
    templateUrl: '/views/home.html',
    resolve: {
     
    },
    onEnter: function(){

    }
});
```

When I switch between Vue Components, the Created/Mounted event of the each Vue component (callee and called) is getting called.

**Example Vue Components:**

**HomeComponent.Vue**

```
  async created() { //This is called every time it is switched to other component
       await this.getHomeData();
       this.loading = false;
}
```

**SupportComponent.Vue**

```
  created() { //This is called every time it is switched to other component
      this.$store.dispatch('getAllSupportProp');
      this.loadDetails();
}
```

In angular app, when I swtich from ***HomeComponent.Vue*** to ***SupportComponent.Vue*** or vice-versa, created/mounted events of both the components are getting called while it should only call the target component's created event.

When I run the Vue app alone (not with AngularJS), the switching between components doesn't have this problem (Callee component doesn't get called).

Comment: Not an agular question, please remove the tag `angular`

Comment: @temp_user - it's probably angular that's causing the issue

Comment: Not `angular`, `angularjs`

Comment: @temp_user removed angular tag.

Comment: oh, right, sorry

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. It's complex and needs to be investigated in whole. This behaviour is most likely depends on the adapter you use (likely ngVue) but you didn't mention it like it's not important.

Comment: @EstusFlask I have updated the question to include ngVue. Also, I'm trying to create a small mcve. I can't share the one which I'm currently facing issue with because It's a very big project and also it belongs to the organization that I work for.